# Is there going to be a version of Stack Overflow for musicians?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm wondering is there going to be a "music flow" site?

I saw Stack Overflow has a whole bunch of other kind of sites including photography, but nothing for musicians?

Comment: you mean this? http://music.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Meysam - it doesn't appear on SO's footer as it's still in beta, but...

Comment: Wow... I didn't find that in the links below the site... :D Yeah .. I meant exactly like that! :D Post it as an answer so I could accept it..

Comment: @Chris - that site's still in Beta!  SE is getting like Google :)

Comment: For reference, you can get a more comprehensive listing of sites here: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: It is interesting to me to understand why somebody downvoted my question? At the time when this was asked, there was no official music.stackexchange.com, the site was beta and not many people knew about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[music.stackexchange.com](http://music.stackexchange.com)

> This is a free, community driven Q&A for musicians, students, and
>   enthusiasts.

Comment: "There's a Stack for that". (Dear Apple: Please don't sue me)

Answer (score 6):

Now that you have the links to the specific site and the *complete* list of all sites, you may be wondering what to do if you have a site idea that doesn't exist.  Don't post here!  Head over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and see if there's already a proposal, and consider creating one if not!

As an aside, I'm one of the mods for the Music site.  Welcome!  Please avoid posting about listening to music, identifying songs, lists of resources, or shopping recommendations ... and we'll be very happy to have you! :P

Comment: Ah... That's great! I actually need the music site to ask some questions about music theory, djing and computer processing music :D